# How do I alter the #weight of the content generated by the upload.module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes

On my Drupal powered website, I want to list available downloads at the top of a node page (within a narrow float:right `<div>`), not at the bottom where they normally appear.

Within my theme, I've overridden the `theme_upload_attachments()` function to generate a `<div>` of width 40%, but this is showing up at the bottom of the page.

Within the `upload.module` file is code that controls where the attachments are listed on the page:

```
// function upload_nodeapi(), line #284 of upload.module
$node->content['files'] = array(
    '#value' => theme('upload_attachments', $node->files),
    '#weight' => 50,
);
```

If I manually hack this #weight to -1, my custom list of attachments shows where I want, floating at the righthand side of the top of the content area.

However, I don't want to manually hack the core file `upload.module`, as my changes will be lost next time I apply an upgrade (say, for a security patch).

How/Where do I modify the #weight of `content['files']` within my theme code?
Or, am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a module to do this, not just a theme. A module can implement hook_nodeapi(), which will give it a chance to change the contents of that $node->content array before it's rendered. If your module is named 'upload_tweaker' for example, you'd use the following function:

```
function upload_tweaker_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
  if ($op == 'view') {
    $node->content['files']['#weight'] = -1;
  }
}
```

Each module gets a crack at changing the node during this 'nodeapi' event; if you want to change the stuff that's added by one module, you need to make sure that your module loads after it. This can be done by naming it something like 'zzz', or by changing its "weight" field in the system table of your site's database. Modules can be weighted just like form elements.

[api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi) has more information.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I've now implemented this little module and it is working exactly as I need. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For those who uses CCK and want to alter body weight:

CCK module uses pre_render function

```
/**
 * Pre-render callback to adjust weights of non-CCK fields.
 */
function content_alter_extra_weights($elements) {
  if (isset($elements['#content_extra_fields'])) {
    foreach ($elements['#content_extra_fields'] as $key => $value) {
      // Some core 'fields' use a different key in node forms and in 'view'
      // render arrays. Check we're not on a form first.
      if (!isset($elements['#build_id']) && isset($value['view']) && isset($elements[$value['view']])) {
        $elements[$value['view']]['#weight'] = $value['weight'];
      }
      elseif (isset($elements[$key])) {
        $elements[$key]['#weight'] = $value['weight'];
      }
    }
  }
  return $elements;
}
```

So due to this callback you are not able to alter weight using normal behavior.

You should do this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  // Only for node pages.
  if ($op == 'view' && $a4) {
    $body_weight = 15 // Any weight.
    $node->content['#content_extra_fields']['body']['weight'] = $body_weight; // This value CCK module will use to alter body weight in the callback from above.
  }
}
```